# Is it necessary to update photo on Resume during job application?

Tags: resume, job-search

On job application, either they request with or without photo, do I need to update my photo on my Resume?

Comment: If they request a photo, you deliver a photo. What do you mean by update?

Comment: How to "accept" your comment @JoeStrazzere? lol

Comment: @nvoigt I mean to update existing photo on my Resume (if I should deliver photo)..

Comment: What locale is this, and which industry sector? In the EU at least, asking for a photo would be opening a company up to accusations of bias and discrimination. Certainly I have never seen a CV in the UK which included a photo of the applicant.

Comment: You say that @MarkBooth, I was of the same ilk in the UK and was rather irked when I moved to Lux to find it pretty mandatory. You don't have to do it, but everyone else is and if you don't you could be left behind.... It's annoying me still now, a photo doesn't show of my skills, but alas, old practices die hard

Comment: In the UK, we are moving towards removing anything possibly discriminatory from CVs, including things like blanking gender and first names when passing CVs from HR to managers selecting interviewees. Initiatives such as Athena Swan are becoming increasingly important in the UK STEMM job market.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> do I need to update my photo on my Resume?

If they require a photo, use a recent photo. It doesn't have to be new, but it shouldn't be more than a year or two old.

It should also be a somewhat "professional" photo. Basically, a head-shot while you are dressed in business attire. You don't have to have them professionally done, but don't use a selfie, or a vacation photo of you in swimwear while holding a drink.

(For a very few professions like acting or modeling, you must provide specific professional portfolio photos, and the "rules" are very different. I'm assuming yours is not one of those cases.)

If they don't request a photo, don't provide one.

Note that in many locales, it would be extremely odd to request a photo. In some locales, it would be illegal. I do understand that it still common in some locales.

Comment: You need to be clear about which country you're referring to in your answer.  In the United States, for example, your CV/résumé will be automatically rejected if it has a photo of the applicant on it. They're afraid of getting sued (read: discrimination).